# How to replace one class with another in a test and check that its method was called?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, wrapper

I want to replace one class with another in a test and check that its method was called.

An example of what I want to do is the following code:

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class A:
    def some_method(self):
        print("A")


class B:
    def some_method(self):
        print("B")


def some_function():
    a = A()
    a.some_method()


def test_some_function():
    with patch("__main__.A", new=B) as mocked_a:
        some_function()
        assert mocked_a.some_method.called_once()
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided, you are attempting to use the unittest.mock library to patch the class A with a new class B and then check if the `some_method` was called.
However, there are some issues in your code, including incorrect usage of the patch context manager. In this corrected code, we use the patch context manager to replace class A with class B and to mock the print function.
Then, we check if the print function was called passing to it the string `B` which is the output of `some_method` of class B.
Here is my solution:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class A:
    def some_method(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    def some_method(self):
        print("B")

def some_function():
    a = A()
    a.some_method()

def test_some_function():
    with patch("__main__.A", new=B):
        with patch("__main__.print") as mock_print:
            some_function()
            mock_print.assert_called_with("B")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_some_function()
```

Comment: In my case, I'm not interested in the print function. Is there a way to check that some_method has been called?

Comment: Okay, in place of "with patch("__main__.print") as mock_print:" past this line "with patch("__main__.B.some_method") as mock_some_method:" and change this line "mock_print.assert_called_with("B")" to this line "mock_some_method.assert_called_once()"

Answer (score 0):

#### Use argument `wraps` of class mock.Mock

A possible solution for your problem could be the use of the `wraps` attribute of the class `mock.Mock` (see at [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and search for `wraps`). So your code become:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock    # <--- HERE I have added Mock in the import

class A:
    def some_method(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    def some_method(self):
        print("B")

def some_function():
    a = A()
    a.some_method()

def test_some_function():
    #with patch("__main__.A", new=B) as mocked_a:  # <--- HERE I have substitute
                                                   #      new=B with wraps=B()
    with patch("__main__.A") as mocked_a:
        mocked_a.return_value = Mock(wraps=B())
        some_function()
        assert mocked_a.some_method.called_once()

test_some_function()
```

The output of the execution of my code is the following:

```
B
```

So this shows that when it is called the instruction `a.some_method()` is executed the method `B.some_method()` instead of `A.some_method()` that is **an instance of class A has been replaced with an instance of class B** as you request in your question.